# How to make a method to wait till another method complete it work in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, methods, completion-block

Consider this scenario.

```
-(void) mainMethod
{
   [self subMethod1];
   [self subMethod2];
}
```

**My assumption:**

When calling the `mainMethod`, it will call the `subMethod1` first, then the `subMethod2`. But, there is no rule that says "After completing the `subMethod1` only, the `subMethod2` should get called". If I use some delay lines or some animation with duration in `subMethod1`, the control won't wait for it completion. It will just start the next process. So, the `subMethod2` can be called before the `subMethod1` completes its work. Am I right?

**Question:**

How can I make subMethod2 to wait, till subMethod1 completes its work?

Note: I don't want to place `subMethod2` into `subMethod1`

Comment: look into blocks, or GCD

Comment: Just curious, would this work? `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] performSelector:@selector(subMethod1) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];` and on the next line call `subMethod2` normally.

Comment: @matsr, I think that might work, but also will block the UI, using completition blocks or GCD you won't block the UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a completion block (like UIView animations have blocks that are executed after the animations happen).

If you're not familiar with blocks, take a look at [Apple's Short Practical Guide to Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html).

Comment: Your link is broken ;) the `_` before `index` at the end should not be there ;) Here's the correct link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html ;)